# how to find the prime factors of a number?spent hours trying to figure out why both the if and else are executed simultaneously

Tags: python

'''    #i want to print the prime factors of num
                 #for the last two outputs should the else statement not 
                  run and break here.as the if condition is full filled
                 #if i break here how does it continue to  else'''

```
num=147
v=0

val=0
for i in range(2,num):


    if num%i==0:

        for x in range(2,i):

            if i%x==0 :
                print(i)
                print(x)
                print(i/x)
                break    
            else:

                v = i
    else:
        continue


    print('primefacs ',v)
```

Python 3.8.1 (default, Feb  2 2020, 08:37:37)

```
primefacs  3
primefacs  7
21
3
7.0
primefacs  21
49
7
7.0
primefacs  49
```

Comment: Could you explain your problem in more detail? What is the expected output?

Comment: i want the output as the prime factors of a number.but the if  statement as for the first two outputs are right but for the last two the if statement checks for the divisibility,the input bypasses the if statement in proceeds to else which by theory it should not do; maybe its a syntax prob

Answer (score 0):

The `else` clause should be associated with the `for`-loop, not the `if`-statement in your inner loop part.

```
num = 147
v = 0

for i in range(2, num):
    if num % i == 0:
        for x in range(2, i):
            if i % x == 0:
                print(i)
                print(x)
                print(i / x)
                break
        # comes here if we didn't hit the `break` above
        else:
            v = i
    else:
        continue
    print('primefacs ', v)
```

Output:

```
primefacs  3
primefacs  7
21
3
7.0
primefacs  7
49
7
7.0
primefacs  7
```